# Upload multiple files at once to server with Summernote File

Tags: php, jquery, summernote

What changes, please, can I make to the code below, so that my `upload.php` file can receive multiple files which I would them loop through to process? I have been trying to upload multiple files at once to server using Summernote. Although, I select multiple files from my laptop for the upload, only one file gets uploaded. I feel certain that the PHP file which handles the upload is not the problem because it receives only one file even if I select multiple files for upload. Below is how the JQuery code looks like

```
$('.summernote-mini').summernote({
    height: 200,
    tabsize: 2,
    callbacks: {
        onFileUpload: function(files) {
            callBack(files[0]);
        },
    }
});
```

**Callback Function**

```
function callBack(files) {
    
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('media_upload[]', files);
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function() { //Handle progress upload
            let myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false);
            return myXhr;
        }
        
    }).done(function(reponse){
        
        //I handle the response here
        
    });
}
```

Regardless of the number of files I select to upload, `count($_FILES['media_upload']['name'])` gives me `1` in my e.g `upload.php` file which handles the server side file upload. What could be the solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you want is to build a POST request containing all the selected files ? It seams that  Summernote sends a POST request for each file, though, as the callback is called for each new file.

Comment: I would like to know if what changes I can make to the code so that it sends all the files I select to the PHP upload file instead of sending just 1

Comment: Yes, I would want to build  a POST request containing all the selected files

Comment: Well, does your `<input type=file>` is with the `multiple` attribute ? Or do you want to select the files one by one ?

Comment: Yes my `<input type=file>` has the multiple attribute so currently, I am able to select multiple files.

Comment: Then try to replace `callBack(files[0]);` with `callBack(files);` , it may work

Comment: Hi, I have replaced `callBack(files[0]);` with `callBack(files);` However,  Out of four files which I selected, only one was uploaded

Comment: I have now edited my question and added the PHP code

Comment: The PHP part isn't the problem for now. Before that you should make sure that the JS works correctly. Add a `console.log(files);` and  `console.log(data);` before the `$.ajax` and see what your browser console gives you

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. You were right about saying "replace `callBack(files[0]);` with `callBack(files);` After doing that, I also added `var iLength = files.length;

  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < iLength; i++){
   data.append("inline_gallery_media_upload[]", files[i]);
  }` and it worked

Comment: You're welcome. It makes sense that you need to append each file of the array one by one to `data` but I'm not familiar with JQuery, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving assistance from @Fravadona I got the solution to the problem.
I replaced `callBack(files[0]);` with `callBack(files);`as @Fravadona suggested.

Then, in the call back function, I replaced  `data.append('media_upload[]', files);` with the code below:

```
var iLength = files.length;

var i;
for(i = 0; i < iLength; i++){
    data.append("media_upload[]", files[i]);
}
```

So the correct code has become this:

```
$('.summernote-mini').summernote({
    height: 200,
    tabsize: 2,
    callbacks: {
        onFileUpload: function(files) {
        callBack(files);
        },
    }
});
```

And the call back function has become this:

```
function callBack(files) {

    let data = new FormData();
    var iLength = files.length;

    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < iLength; i++){
        data.append("media_upload[]", files[i]);
    }
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function() { //Handle progress upload
            let myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false);
            return myXhr;
        }
    
    }).done(function(reponse){
    
        //I handle the response here
    
    });
}
```

So now, I am able to successfully upload multiple files at once using Summmernote.